# R: How to create new variable based on name of other column

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I would like to create a new variable based on the **name** of other columns, so that I can move from a wide to a long dataset.

What I have:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                       alpha_1 = c(50, 30, 20, 6),
                       alpha_2 = c(30, 20, 15, 10),
                       beta_1 = c(50, 30, 20, 6),
                       beta_2 = c(30, 20, 15, 10))
```

and what I'm hoping to manipulate it into:

```
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2","3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
                            "4", "4"),
                  condition = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  measure = c("alpha", "alpha", "beta", "beta","alpha", "alpha", "beta", "beta",
                             "alpha", "alpha", "beta", "beta","alpha", "alpha", "beta", "beta"),
                  value = c(50, 30, 50, 30, 30, 20, 30, 20, 20, 15, 20 ,15, 6, 10, 6, 10))
```

A typical "melt" doesn't work here, as I don't know how to do it based on the column's name. I'd like to do this for all the columns in the dataset. Thanks so much for any help or guidance you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to pivot into 'long' format and then do the `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = 'measure') %>%
   separate(measure, into = c('measure', 'condition'))
#   name measure condition value
#1     1   alpha         1    50
#2     1   alpha         2    30
#3     1    beta         1    50
#4     1    beta         2    30
#5     2   alpha         1    30
#6     2   alpha         2    20
#7     2    beta         1    30
#8     2    beta         2    20
#9     3   alpha         1    20
#10    3   alpha         2    15
#11    3    beta         1    20
#12    3    beta         2    15
#13    4   alpha         1     6
#14    4   alpha         2    10
#15    4    beta         1     6
#16    4    beta         2    10
```